# To compare two lists and find the similarities

Tags: python, perl, awk

I have a list like this one:

```
C
E
```

I want to find these in the following tables (table 1) and write them into the second table (table 2)

Does anyone have a python or perl script to do this?

Table 1:

```
A   MU_ADO_2    1099    MU_ADO_2.1099   o   o   o   o   o   o   o   o   o   o   7.82436 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  2   4   0   2   0                                                                               
A   MU_ADO_2    1105    MU_ADO_2.1105   327.008 s_2_merged  Resistance  G   GT  81  0   2   132 79  31.5281 s_6_merged  Resistance  G   GT  8   0   1   8   7   34.9813 s_3_merged  Suseptible  G   GT  7   0   0   3   7   7.82436 s_7_merged  Suseptible  G   GT  2   0   0   4   2
A   MU_ADO_2    1110    MU_ADO_2.1110   515.963 s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AT  113 96  1   2   110 31.5281 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AT  7   8   0   0   7   16.3388 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AT  4   7   0   0   4   13.808  s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AT  3   3   0   0   3
A   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
B   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
B   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
B   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
D   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
D   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
D   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
D   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
D   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
D   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
D   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
D   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
D   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
E   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
E   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
E   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
E   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
F   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
F   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
F   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
F   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
F   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
```

Table 2:

```
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
C   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
E   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
E   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
E   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
E   MU_ADO_2    1120    MU_ADO_2.1120   1.00E+06    s_2_merged  Resistance  A   AG  169 107 1   167 1   36.1308 s_6_merged  Resistance  A   AG  8   9   0   8   0   35.6751 s_7_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  7   2   0   7   0   20.9415 s_3_merged  Suseptible  A   AG  5   8   0   5   0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what do you mean by "C E"? What are you trying to find?

Comment: Now that your tables were edited (thanks F.J) my only question is What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative, in python:

```
keys = ['C', 'E']
with open('out.txt', 'a') as out:
    with open('test.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            for key in keys:
                if line.startswith(key):
                    out.write(line)
                    break
```

`test.txt` is a file with your table 1, copy-pasted.
`out.txt` is a file where you get your table 2

Comment: You need a `break` after the `write` in your loop to make it efficent, or, equivalently, in two lines on Python 2.7 - `with open('out.txt', 'a') as out, open('test.txt') as f:` then `out.writelines(line for line in f if any(line.startswith(key) for key in keys))`

Comment: @agf, I included a break. For the rest, I prefer to keep the code as simple as possible for the OP who seemingly is a newcomer in SO.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't recommending the golfed version really, with the break the loops + if is good.

Answer (score 3):

Since you included the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) tag I'm assuming you are open to other *nix utilities, here is a `sed` solution:

```
sed '/^[^CE]/d' table1.txt > table2.txt
```

This will remove all lines from table1.txt that do not start with C or E.

Answer (score 3):

How about *grep*

```
grep -e '^[CE]' source.file
```

and you can redirect that into a new file as well:

```
grep -e '^[CE]' source.file > dest.file
```

Comment: Nice! The progression from `awk` to `sed` to `grep` keeps leading to simpler answers.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is: "How can if filter this file to only see the entries with first field equal to `C` or `E`?"

Then the following should work:

```
awk '$1 ~ /[CE]/ { print $0 }' yourfile > outfile
```

If you want to save some keystrokes at the expense of clarity, the following also works:

```
awk '$1 ~ /[CE]/' yourfile > outfile
```

Comment: It takes all of three more characters in Perl.  So what? You also have infinitely better regexes — and a real™ programming language. Note also that your code does not do what you says it does.  Whoops!

Comment: @tchrist Relax, Perl is better than awk, I'm not trying to start a holy-war, I'll remove the comment that upset you. But this works as far as I can tell, let me know what error you found.

Comment: The comment was just provocative is all. However your code detects whether the first field contains either a C or an E, which is quite different from saying `$1 == "C" || $1 == "E"`, which is what your “ first field equal to `C` or `E`” was saying. I am not making a judgement call on correctness, just pointing out that the code description did not match what the code was doing. One Perl solution  is `perl -ne '/^[CE]/&&print'` although I prefer `print if /^[CE]/` as much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "C E" list comes from a file:

```
awk '
    FILENAME == ARGV[1] {list[$1]; next}
    $1 in list {print}
' list.txt table1 > table2
```